# Performance issue with webtest and grails

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, webtest

I have read the documentation for Grails and Webtest in this site:

http://www.grails.org/plugin/webtest

And it's very unupdated. Most of the scripts listed there doesn't work.

I am looking a way to run a working alternative of -nostart listed there.

This is because it's very slow to rerun tests. Or maybe a way to run webtests from outside of Grails

Can you give me any pointer?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webtest plugin changed from version 1.3 to use the new hooks provided by the grails test-app script. Unfortunately one piece of functionality not provided by test-app is the -nostart option.

You could try using

```
grails interactive
```

then

```
test-app -functional
```

hitting enter should re-run the functional tests without doing a complete restart of grails.

I've also removed the -nostart option from the documentation. All the other documentation should be up to date. What other scripts did not work?

You can raise issues here: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILSPLUGINS/component/12994

Comment: Thanks, I already use the grails interactive option. Its there a way to do the -nostart option, even if I have to modify the code to work?

Comment: Sometimes when some test fails the report only show a few, instead of showing all. I have tried to raise this issue, but I don't have a way to signup.

Comment: You'd need to modify _GrailsTest.groovy in GRAILS_HOME/scripts. If you look at line 335 at functionalTestPhasePreparation and functionalTestPhaseCleanup you can see it calling runApp() and stopServer(). You'd need to stop it doing that if you supply the -nostart option

Comment: You can signup for JIRA here: http://jira.codehaus.org/secure/Signup!default.jspa

Comment: I had raised an issue: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILSPLUGINS-2290, thanks for the info, though